# MySQL - Many to One from Room to Apartment: how to get the lowest priced room for an apartment without having to iterate through all the rooms?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Those are my models, Room and Apartment.

My question is, if I wan't to get the lowest priced room for an apartment, do I Absolutely must first get all the rooms, iterate through them, and determine the lowest priced room?

Is it possible to perhaps add FK from Apartment to Room which will automatically change to lowest priced room if i enter/edit/delete new Rooms for an apartment?

Does MySQL provide some mechanisms to workaround this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min MIN() Could you provided some more information on either the Query and/or the DB Table Fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT apartment.ID, 
    MIN(room.Price) 
FROM room 
    JOIN apartment ON room.apartmentID=apartment.ID 
GROUP BY apartment.ID;
```

I'm obviously guessing your relations.

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not include the structure of your 2 tables, I'll work off of assuming you have them in the following basic format:

Apartment (ApartmentID, Name...)
Room (RoomID, ApartmentID, Price...)

```
select RoomID from Room where ApartmentID = x order by price desc limit 1
```

That should give you the cheapest room in that specific apartment. You'd need to iterate through all of the apartments to get the cheapest room associated with them (depending on how you display them) and iterating through Apartment would be far less query intensive than doing it by Room

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE apartment = "apartment1" ORDERED BY price DESC
```

The cheapest room will be the first element of selection. Add inverse relation between rooms and corresponding apartment

Comment: This will result in ALL the rooms, regardless of which Apartment they belong to, to be accounted for when ordering by price

Comment: "ORDERED BY proce DESC" will return the most expensive room first.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT
  rooms.price,
  apartments.id
FROM rooms
JOIN apartments
WHERE rooms.apartment_id = apartments.id
ORDER BY rooms.price ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Add to the SELECT-list whatever you need, if this is all you need, the information is of course already in the rooms table, so there would be no need to JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to perhaps add FK from Apartment to Room which will automatically change to lowest priced room if i enter/edit/delete new Rooms for an apartment?

No, this is not what foreign keys are for.

Using a FK might be forgiveable if you had a scenario where it was very expensive to identify which of the 'many' side was to be referenced (e.g. you have millions of rooms in each apartment) or where the criteria for selecting the one related entry was based on data outwith the data stored for the 'many'.

But in your case it is simply...

```
SELECT room.id
FROM room
WHERE room.apartment=?
ORDER BY room.price ASC
LIMIT 0,1
```

(where ? denotes the identifier for selecting the apartment).

Or if you want the cheapest price in all apartments, something like....

```
SELECT apartment.name, apartment.id...., MIN(room.price)
FROM room INNER JOIN apartment 
  ON (room.apt_id=apartment.id)
GROUP BY apartment.name, apartment.id....
```

Find ing which room in each apartment is the cheapest is bit more involved - consider the scenario where you've got several rooms each with the same (lowest) price. You'd need to use the [max concat trick](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html).